# Numba Function Error: Handling 1D and 2D Arrays Differently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I'm encountering an error while using Numba-optimized functions to check if the extent of an n-dimensional box (`n >= 1`) is larger than a minimum value along corresponding dimensions. The functions `get_extent` and `is_larger_than_min` are decorated with `@njit`.

Here are the functions:

```
@njit
def get_extent(box):
    return box[1] - box[0]
```

and

```
@njit
def is_larger_than_min(box, extent_min):
    extent = get_extent(box)
    return np.all(extent >= extent_min)
```

When I pass a 2D array `box1` and its corresponding `extent_min1`, everything works fine. However, when I pass a 1D array `box2` and its `extent_min2`, I encounter an error.

```
box1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5]])   # shape (2, n), i.e. (n>1)-dimensional box
extent_min1 = np.array([4, 4, 4])   # shape (n,), i.e. extents along each dimension

box2 = np.array([0, 5])   # shape (2,), i.e. (n=1)-dimensional box, or just an interval
extent_min2 = 4   # scalar, i.e. extent (length) along this single dimension

is_larger_than_min(box1, extent_min1)   # works fine
is_larger_than_min(box2, extent_min2)   # raises error
```

The error message I receive is not very informative, but since the function `is_larger_than_min` *without* `@njit` works just fine with any types of inputs, it is obviously related to handling scalars and arrays differently within the Numba-optimized functions. How can I modify these functions to handle both scalars and arrays without encountering errors? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: It would be helpful to include the complete error message in the question.  It might not be informative to you, but others might find useful information in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `get_extent` function to always return an array with at least 1 dimension so that you always have an array passed to `np.all` which is required in the numba implementation:

```
@njit
def get_extent(box):
    return np.atleast_1d(np.asarray(box[1] - box[0]))
```